# Select only specific values from JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

EDIT - What is the purpose of marking a question as duplicate?  Earn some points and get a little wiseass kick? You cannot know that this question will not help someone. The answers to the question that this "duplicated" would not have answered my question in my limited knowledge, but the gentleman who answered MY question did.
-EDIT

I am looking to select just one value from a list of JSON data, the 24 hr price percentage change:

```
{
    "id": "stellar", 
    "name": "Stellar", 
    "symbol": "XLM", 
    "rank": "6", 
    "price_usd": "0.570132", 
    "price_btc": "0.00005009", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "672209000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "10187093680.0", 
    "available_supply": "17867956333.0", 
    "total_supply": "103629819514", 
    "max_supply": null, 
    "percent_change_1h": "1.8", 
    "percent_change_24h": "16.65", 
    "percent_change_7d": "23.95", 
    "last_updated": "1516839244"
}
```

and at the moment, my current code, which is just to test if what I have thus far works at all, returns simply `[object Object]` :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/stellar/',
  function (data) {
   document.body.append(data);
  });
 });
</script>
```

I want to isolate - and to start, just to show - only that `"percent_change_24h"` and work from there.

**Thank you.**

Comment: parse the data `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: @ChaseChoi `$.getJSON` does that automatically.

Comment: in that case, it's not JSON the OP is dealing with in his *request for code*

Comment: The JSON data you got from your URL is an array. please use array index to get the data you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/stellar/ returns the array:

```
[
    {
        "id": "stellar", 
        "name": "Stellar", 
        "symbol": "XLM", 
        "rank": "6", 
        "price_usd": "0.566242", 
        "price_btc": "0.00004991", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "674523000.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "10117586651.0", 
        "available_supply": "17867955133.0", 
        "total_supply": "103629819514", 
        "max_supply": null, 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.26", 
        "percent_change_24h": "16.45", 
        "percent_change_7d": "21.53", 
        "last_updated": "1516840744"
    }
]
```

So in order to get access to the `percent_change_24h` field you need `data[0].percent_change_24h`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/stellar/',
                function (data) {
                    document.body.append(data[0].percent_change_24h);
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This works, but why the [0]?

Comment: @Alex Because the returned data is an array, and it has only one element (its index is 0), so we use `data[0]` to get that object and then use `.` to get the particular property

Comment: @Alex You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can access directly using that key `percent_change_24h`:

```js
var data = {
  "id": "stellar",
  "name": "Stellar",
  "symbol": "XLM",
  "rank": "6",
  "price_usd": "0.570132",
  "price_btc": "0.00005009",
  "24h_volume_usd": "672209000.0",
  "market_cap_usd": "10187093680.0",
  "available_supply": "17867956333.0",
  "total_supply": "103629819514",
  "max_supply": null,
  "percent_change_1h": "1.8",
  "percent_change_24h": "16.65",
  "percent_change_7d": "23.95",
  "last_updated": "1516839244"
};

console.log(data['percent_change_24h']);
document.body.append(data['percent_change_24h']);
// in your case document.body.append(data['percent_change_24h']);
```

**Hope it helps!**